# Como puedo comparar distancias usando coordenadas geograficas?

Tags: postgresql, flutter, google-api

Tengo una base de datos en la cual registro un reporte y como atributos se tienen la longitud y latitud de un sitio, esto se captura desde una app móvil, el detalle es que me gustaría comparar la cercanía que hay entre reportes para evitar que suban varios reportes de un mismo sitio.
Actualmente estoy usando la API de Google, para la base de datos postgresql.
Utilicé distanceTo y funciona bien cuando se tiene que comparar con otra pero no tengo idea para hacerlos con las que están en la base de datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque su pregunta no es algo que solamente se pueda hacer en flutter, sino lo que usted busca hacer es un cálculo matemático, para ser más específico la fórmula del semiverseno, a continuación comparto una implementación que hice para flutter.

Primero, debe agregar la siguiente dependencia en su archivo pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  vector_math: any
```

Luego importe las siguientes bibliotecas en el archivo en donde desea invocar los siguiente métodos

```
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart' as math;
import 'dart:math';

double calculateDistance(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {
  int radiusEarth = 6371;
  double distanceKm;
  double distanceMts;
  double dlat, dlng;
  double a;
  double c;

  //Convertimos de grados a radianes
  lat1 = math.radians(lat1);
  lat2 = math.radians(lat2);
  lng1 = math.radians(lng1);
  lng2 = math.radians(lng2);
  // Fórmula del semiverseno
  dlat = lat2 - lat1;
  dlng = lng2 - lng1;
  a = sin(dlat / 2) * sin(dlat / 2) +
      cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(dlng / 2)) * (sin(dlng / 2));
  c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a));

  distanceKm = radiusEarth * c;
  print('Distancia en Kilométros:$distanceKm');
  distanceMts = 1000 * distanceKm;
  print('Distancia en Metros:$distanceMts');

  return distanceKm;
  //return distanceMts;
}
```

Cabe mencionar que el anterior algoritmo es para calcular la distancia entre dos puntos de acuerdo a sus latitudes y longitudes, así que la comparación que busca realizar solo quedaría a consideración de cómo utilizar el anterior algoritmo.

Si desea conocer más a fondo sobre como y que son esos cálculos matemáticos que se realizaron en la anterior función le comparto un [enlace](https://www.deformasymapas.com/blog/post/2/) que habla más a detalle sobre el tema además de que en el hay una implementación de este mismo algoritmo pero hecho en python